# How to pass int parameter to DATASET implemented interface method in C#

Tags: c#, methods, dataset, parameter-passing

Below are the quick read about my code implemented

Declared interface in ILogic.cs file.

```
DataSet updateStatus();
```

Return interface in CLogic.cs  file.

```
public DataSet updateStatus()
{
    return this.Repository.updateStatus();
}
```

Interface method implementation in Repository.cs file, What is the correct way to implement this method.

```
public DataSet updateStatus()
{
    try
    {
        dataSet = new DataSet();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedures.JobStausUpdate, conETLITG))
        {
            conITG.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(jobid);
            adapt.Fill(dataSet);
            conITG.Close();
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
    catch (Exception es)
    {
        throw es;
    }
}
```

Calling method as below in Program.cs file so how can I pass `@Execution_Job_ID` in `updateStatus`

```
intjobId=86746;    
commonLogic.updateStatus(jobId);
```

SQL Store Procedure

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE JobStausUpdate  
    ( @Execution_Job_ID INT
)   
AS   
  BEGIN  
  SELECT TOP 3   
               ji.jobname,   
               jel.*   
    INTO       #tempjobstatus   
    FROM       joblog jel    
    INNER JOIN jobinfo ji   
    ON         jel.jobid=ji.jobid   
    WHERE      jel.jobid IN (67,89,44)   
    AND        jel.joblogid <= @Execution_Job_ID   
    ORDER BY   2 DESC  
      
 DECLARE @ARefresh  VARCHAR(30),   
      @BRefresh  VARCHAR(30),   
      @statusId INT,  
      @statusReturn INT  
   SET @ARefresh =   
    (   
           SELECT jobstatus   
           FROM   #tempjobstatus   
           WHERE  jobname ='aRefresh')  
     IF (@ARefresh = 'Failed')   
    BEGIN   
      SET @BRefresh =   
      (   
             SELECT jobstatus   
             FROM   #tempjobstatus   
             WHERE  jobname ='bRefresh')   
      IF (@BRefresh = 'In Progress')   
      BEGIN   
        SET @statusId =   
        (   
               SELECT joblogid   
               FROM   #tempjobstatus   
               WHERE  jobname ='bRefresh')   
        UPDATE joblog   
        SET    jobstatus = 'Failed'   
        WHERE  joblogid = @statusId   
        SET    @statusReturn=1   
      END   
      ELSE SET @statusReturn =0  
    END   
 ELSE  IF (@ARefresh = 'Completed')   
    BEGIN   
      SET @BRefresh =   
      (   
             SELECT jobstatus   
             FROM   #tempjobstatus   
             WHERE  jobname ='bRefresh')   
      IF (@BRefresh = 'In Progress')   
      BEGIN   
        SET @statusId =   
        (   
               SELECT joblogid   
               FROM   #tempjobstatus   
               WHERE  jobname ='bRefresh')   
        UPDATE joblog   
        SET    jobstatus = 'Completed'   
        WHERE  joblogid = @statusId   
        SET    @statusReturn=1   
      END   
      ELSE SET @statusReturn =0  
    END   
    ELSE   
   BEGIN   
    SET @statusReturn=0   
    END 
    SELECT @statusReturn
    SELECT * FROM   #tempjobstatus
   
 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but you just need to update your Interface to include the int you want to pass then change your cmc.Parameters.Add.

`DataSet updateStatus(int jobid);`

`cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@JobID",jobid));`

Comment: you understand correctly now it working as expected.